# Cannot call a function in java from JSP and JS

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am trying to call a function from the controller with url `/OHRSFrontSheet` and the function looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateFrontSheet/{myId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void generateFrontSheet(@RequestParam("myId") Long Id) {
SOP("Creating doc for ID = "+myId);
//Create Document
}
```

My java script is:

```
function createFrontSheet(id) {
 alert(id);
 $.post("/OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet",{Id:id});
}
```

my jsp looks like:

```
<spring:url var="generateFrontSheetUrl"
    value="/OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet(${formId})"/>                                         
<a href="javascript:createFrontSheet(${formId});">Download Doc</a>
```

The problem withe the code is the `alert(id)` in the JS is called but it function `generateFrontSheet()` is not getting called. I get a 404 error.

Am I missing something with respect to the parameter I am passing or the mappings?

Comment: Did you specify correct URL in js file?

Comment: @kundanbora: this is all the code i have written. JS included

Comment: Can someone please help me with the paramater I am passing in the POST method of JS. Is that correst? and does that call the function exactly the way I want it by passing the parameter.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Silly mistake though. I forgot including my project base url in the JavaScript.

```
function createFrontSheet(id) {
 alert(id);
 $.post("/portal/OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet",{Id:id});
}
```

`/portal` is the base url of my project. :)

Answer (score 0):

look at line

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateFrontSheet/{myId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

here myId is url part.

Now look at this -

```
  $.post("/OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet",{Id:id});
```

here you have to put id as a part of url.

it should be look like this

```
$.post("/OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet/"+id);
```

same thing in jsp

```
value="/OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet/(${formId})"
```

Comment: did not work: again the same error 404.

`HTTP Status 404 - /OHRSFrontSheet/generateFrontSheet/131350`

131350 is my Id...

There is a problem with the mapping i guess

Comment: Use "@PathVariable" instead of "@RequestParam"